# App-Engine Parse a UrlFetch UTF-8 encoded stream

Tags: python, google-app-engine, parsing, encoding, streaming

I am trying to parse an `XML` from a `URL` using the `xml.sax` parser. I know there are other libraries to use but coming from `Java` this is the one I am most familiar with and seems the least complicated to me.

The code I'm using to parse is as follows:

```
parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
handler = MangaHandler()
parser.setContentHandler(handler)
url = urlfetch.Fetch('http://www.mangapanda.com/alphabetical', allow_truncated = False, follow_redirects = False, deadline = False)
xml.sax.parseString(url.content, handler)
```

This returns a SaxException (invalid token) once the parser reaches the first `&` sign:

```
SAXParseException: <unknown>:582:34: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Because `urlfetch` returns a string and not a stream I cannot use the `parse()` (which only works with streams) and am left to use `parseString()` instead. To see if parsing as a stream would fix this I tried:

```
parser.parse(io.StringIO(url.content).encode('utf-8'))
```

but this returns:

```
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
```

I have also tried to use the `urllib2` libraries which do return a stream instead of `urlfetch` but the file is too large and is automatically truncated, leaving me with missing data.

Any Sort of work-around for this would be greatly appreciated as I've spent days getting around one obstacle just to be stopped by another.

Comment: to get unicode, you have to use decode('utf-8'). It also confused me, when I started using Python.

Comment: Havent been able to try this due to an update getting away from me and now I cant roll back -___-

Comment: Didnt work. `parser.parse(io.StringIO(url.content).decode('utf-8'))
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`

Comment: I think you want: `io.StringIO(url.content.decode('utf-8'))` ; you are decoding the url content as utf-8 into a Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.X, the `str` type is actually a byte array that can contain any encoded string.

When downloading content that is encoded as UTF8, you will usually get it as an **encoded** `str` (if it wasn't encoded, it couldn't be an `str`, because `str` is an array of single byte chars). In that case, you should use `decode('utf8')` to convert the encoded `str` to a (decoded) `unicode`, which is basically an array of two-byte chars.

Then you can put the `unicode` instance into a `io.StringIO` instance to create a file like object.